# Periodic linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

It is known that set of all solutions of

$$x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$$

where $A(t)$ is $n\times n$ matrix, forms $n$ dimensional vector space $V$. Now let $A(t)$ be periodic with period $T$ and $W$ be set of all $T$-periodic solutions of above system. It is clear that $\dim W\le\dim V$. It is not hard to find $A(t)$ such that $W$ has zero or full dimension. Is it possible to have $0<\dim W<n$?

Answer (score 1):

This can be already done in the case $A$ has constant coefficients. Consider the system

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \dot{x_1}(t) \\ \dot{x_2}(t) \\ \dot{x_3}(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \\ x_3(t) \end{pmatrix}. $$

The solution space is given by

$$ A \sin(t) \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + B \cos(t) \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + C e^t \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

and you get a two-dimensional subspace of periodic solutions. You can construct many more examples by giving $A$ a block diagonal structure where in each block you know how the solutions behave.